# Scalatest matching options

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have this simple test:

```
test("transform /home into Array(/home)") {
    val path = "/home"
    val expected: Option[Array[String]] = Some(Array("/home"))
    val actual: Option[Array[String]] = luceneService.buildCategoryTree(path)
    actual shouldEqual expected
}
```

And I get this failure:

```
Some(Array("/home")) did not equal Some(Array("/home"))
```

How can this be?

As I understand it the [docs](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#workingWithOptions) state that I should be able to use options in tests

If I change the test to

```
actual.get shouldEqual expected.get
```

it passes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug with the matchers. 
Using `Seq` instead of `Array` works:

```
val expected = Some(Seq("/home"))
val actual = luceneService.buildCategoryTree(path).map(_.toSeq)
actual shouldEqual expected
```

Answer (score 3):

In the sclatest [docs](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#workingWithOptions)

there is a section that says:

> You can work with options using ScalaTest's equality, empty, defined,
> and contain syntax. For example, if you wish to check whether an
> option is None, you can write any of:

so with your test (sorry I do not have de lucerne object), I also think that is some [thing wrong when using arrays](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/491)

> Unfortunately, the current implementation is not able to "properly"
> understand Array equality if arrays are within another container such
> as Set[Array[Int]]. For example, I would have expected the following
> test to pass instead of throwing a TestFailedException:

```
import org.scalatest._

class SetSuite extends FunSuite with Matchers {

  test("transform /home into Array(/home)") {
    val path = "/home"
    val expected: Option[Array[String]] = Some(Array("/home"))
    val actual: Option[Array[String]] = Some(Array(path))
    actual shouldEqual expected
  }
}

[info] SetSuite:
[info] - transform /home into Array(/home) *** FAILED ***
[info]   Some(Array("/home")) did not equal Some(Array("/home")) (TestScalaTest.scala:9)
[info] Run completed in 335 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 1, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] *** 1 TEST FAILED ***
[error] Failed tests:
[error]     SetSuite
[error] (test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 11 s, completed Mar 17, 2016 12:26:25 AM
```

so for testing let's use

```
import org.scalatest._

class SetSuite extends FunSuite with Matchers {

  test("transform /home into Array(/home)") {
    val path = "/home"
    val expected: Option[Array[String]] = Some(Array("/home"))
    val actual: Option[Array[String]] = Some(Array(path))
    actual should contain (Array("/home"))
  }
}

[info] SetSuite:
[info] - transform /home into Array(/home)
[info] Run completed in 201 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Mar 17, 2016 12:33:01 AM
```

Comment: I think, it would more helpful if you just explained what was the problem rather than just pasting some output as evidence that you know what it is :/

Comment: I pointed the issue now, and did the work around, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

This is scalatest's issue with arrays. Same test works just fine if you convert arrays to say vectors or lists